# How do I write an array of attributes to a column after having first cycled through a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So basically what I want to happen is, on my `n.parents` attribute I would like to set a value like `[val1, val2, val3, val4]`.

My setter method looks like this:

```
def parents=(*parents)
  write_attribute(self.base_class.ancestry_column, 
                          if parents.nil? 
                            nil 
                          else 
                            parents.map(&:child_ancestry)
                          end
                 )
end
```

But when I run this, I get this error:

```
> n.parents= a,b
NoMethodError: undefined method `child_ancestry' for #<Array:0x007f9fb0072fb8>
```

In this case, `val1 = a.child_ancestry`, `val2 = b.child_ancestry`...but in theory, I should be able to do `n.parents= a,b,c,d,e,f` and it should work just as well.

P.S. I am trying to write these to the `ancestry_column` of the `base_class` of the object I am updating.

**Edit 1**

After trying both answers below from @zealoushacker and @nathanvda, I keep getting the same `undefined method 'child_ancestry' for #<Array....>` error.

However, if in my console I just do any of those `map` operations, it seems to return fine...so I am even more confused.

Example:

```
[8] pry(main)> n
=> #<Node id: 36, family_tree_id: 2, created_at: "2015-01-28 23:19:28", updated_at: "2015-01-28 23:19:28", name: "Mesty", ancestry: "13/35", ancestry_depth: 0, max_tree_depth: 0>
[9] pry(main)> n.parents
  Node Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
=> [#<Node id: 35, family_tree_id: 2, created_at: "2015-01-28 23:17:36", updated_at: "2015-01-28 23:17:36", name: "Testy", ancestry: "13", ancestry_depth: 0, max_tree_depth: 0>]
[10] pry(main)> n.parents.map(&:child_ancestry)
  Node Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
=> ["13/35"]
[11] pry(main)> n.parents.flatten.map(&:child_ancestry)
  Node Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 35]]
=> ["13/35"]
```

Comment: Can you show us the class definition, because now I am confused how you ever set `n.parents` and where/how `ancestry_column` is defined. It seems like `n.parents` is an association? Yet you are overruling the assignment? Then you are using the `n.parents` to test the flatten?

Comment: @nathanvda This is the gem I am modifying and here are the lines where the `parents` method is defined: https://github.com/tjchambers/ancestry/blob/master/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb#L146-L152

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird to use the splat operator in an assignment, why not do something like

```
def parents=(new_parents)
  ancestry = if new_parents.nil? 
               nil 
             else 
               new_parents = [new_parents] unless new_parents.is_a?(Array)
               new_parents.map(&:child_ancestry).join('/')
             end
  write_attribute(self.base_class.ancestry_column, ancestry)
end
```

and then you can still write

```
n.parents = a,b
```

(which is converted to an array automatically in the assignment).

The splat operator will wrap the given parameter in an array again. So just drop the splat operator. It is used in function calls, on assignments it does not make any sense imho.

*trying it manually:*

The thing you need to try in the console to see if it works:

```
> my_parents = a,b 
> ancestry = my_parents.map(&:child_ancestry) 
> n.ancestry_column = ancestry
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting the same error, aka: `> n.parents= a,b
NoMethodError: undefined method 'child_ancestry' for #<Array:0x007ff7d58a1360>
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@test_tree_app/bundler/gems/ancestry-eb5a3e448112/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb:173:in 'map'`

Comment: I also edited the question with more stuff I have tried.

Comment: Ok, I do not get it. The `new_parents` is an array, so the map should work. It is confusing you use `parents` for both the attribute and the value assigning, this will cause problems. So for clarity I showed (and refactored) the function. Instead of using `write_attribute`, I prefer to just assign the column. If you need to update the value straigt-away, i prefer to use `update_attributes ancestry_column: ancestry`.

Comment: I should note that this is actually inside a gem that I forked - not sure if that affects your recommendation re: `update_attributes`.

Comment: So your logic works, but when I drop it into the gem I am still getting the same error....so I too, am a little confused. The even crazier thing is, when I go through your commands at the console, they seem to work. But when I do this: `> my_parents.map(&:child_ancestry)
NoMethodError: undefined method '["13", "13/35/36/37/38"]_was' for #<Node:0x007ff7d16e2cd0>`

Comment: Ok, can you point my to the original gem or your fork? Could help to get a little more background.

Comment: Here is the fork - https://github.com/tjchambers/ancestry - I also included a link to the exact `parents` method in response to your comment on the question itself.

Comment: Adapted the code to work and be interpreted as parent-ids (if you need them to be branches, you should be using `,` separated list). You only have to make sure the given parameter is an array. This means: writing `n.parents = a,b` will work, writing `n.parents = a` will NOT. I am guessing this is why you get the error. So to avoid confusion, I made sure the code could handle it.

Comment: You know what happened, so the first time I tried this it failed as well. But I realized I am getting the same error. But then I remembered I was having a similar issue before, and it turned out that Spring was caching the old version of the gem. So I stopped it, reloaded the console and voila....both your latest version and the one before worked! Thanks!

Comment: @zealoushacker You would be right. That's why I haven't allocated the bounty yet....because I am not sure who to give it to. I wish I could split it between both of u :(

Comment: @zealoushacker sure, your option would also work, but imho it is better to just avoid using a splat operator in an assignment, and there would be no need for the flatten (the splat just adds an array around what already is an array).

Comment: @nathanvda Why would anyone use a splat operator then, if that attribute is already an array? To ensure/force it to be an array?

Comment: You are using it in an assignment, which does not make sense. It is generally used in a (normal) method, to just "swallow" all given variables. E.g. something like `printf`. I rarely use it, but it allows for flexible parameter-lists. E.g. in a gem I developed I used it for especially that reason: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb#L16 I do not really like it, because I prefer a more explicit "contract" in my function calls.

Comment: Also your comment makes me wonder if you actually _read_ my answer?

Comment: While I would love to have earned the 100pt bounty, I think @nathanvda is absolutely right about explicit contracts in function signatures, and totally deserves the bounty. 

marcamillion: [read up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) about the idea of design by contract - if you don't already know the concept, it's very powerful in software design. Also [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DesignByContract).

Comment: @nathanvda I absolutely did *read* your answer. I am not sure if you actually read MY comment. I wasn't asking what the effect of using an splat operator was....I was asking, IF the attribute being accepted is already an array, why would anyone use the splat operator.  Slightly nuanced, but quite a different question. In fact, it is your answer that shed light on the usage of the splat operator that caused me to ask that question in the first place. Your other comment did add more clarity.

Comment: I replied to your comment didn't I? But after reading my answer, I felt I had already tried to explain that in my answer, so that made me wonder (but probably not good/clear enough). The splat operator definitely has a use, just not in an assignment imho.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write:

`parents.flatten.map(&:child_ancestry)`

because the `*parents` splat argument contains an array of arrays, which looks something like this if you inspect it:

`[[#<ChildAncestry:0x000001018d1010>, #<ChildAncestry:0x000001018d0fe8>]]`

Take a look at [Array#flatten](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten).

It takes the above and converts it to something like:

`[#<ChildAncestry:0x000001018d1010>, #<ChildAncestry:0x000001018d0fe8>]`

on which you may then use `map` as you had.

Comment: So your logic makes sense, but when I try it I still get the same error. I am also not sure how to inspect `*parents`.

Comment: Which is this:  `> n.parents= a,b
NoMethodError: undefined method 'child_ancestry' for #<Array:0x007ff7d58a1360>
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@test_tree_app/bundler/gems/ancestry-eb5a3e448112/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb:173:in 'map'`

Comment: I also edited the question with more stuff I have tried.